# Side effects of including .c-files

Tags: c, embedded

Disclaimer: I know that similar questions have been asked already here, but none answers my question.

Compiler used: XC32 v1.44 (based on gcc)
Environment: Embedded (I am also using FreeRTOS, but that should not matter?)

For my project I want a high test code coverage. My Interfaces are quite sleek and I have quite a bit of (private) static functions that I want to be tested separately. So, in my test files, I have included the c-files. Now I can access the static functions and everything would be fine. Only it is not.

I have to point out that I did not exclude the c-files from the project. So the code is most likely compiled twice, once as the single c-file and once as included in the test file.

I do NOT get any compile or linker errors (I read in other questions that I should). Also the code is running properly - mostly.

The code is also accessed twice, once by the tests and once by the regular state machine that still runs in the background.

I have the effect that it looks like everything is duplicated now. So all static variables are created twice and the regular state machine is accessing different static-variables than the test.

Example:

```
static int myInt = 0; // lets assume this would be possible in c...
static void Increment()
{
    ++myInt;
}
static int getIncrement()
{
    return myInt;
}
```

So when the state-machine is calling Increment() and the test is calling getIncrement(), the test still gets 0.

Is that correct or more complicated than I think? I currently have the effect that I call a function (from the included c-file) in my test that opens a handler to something (the handler is stored in a static) but a call (within my test) to a second function that uses that handler claims that is still NULL... this behavior does not fit in my explaination above...

Comment: Asking for side effects. You know the main effect: "So the code is most likely compiled twice, once as the single c-file and once as included in the test file." And you even describe unpleasant effects. What else do you need to know?

Comment: Something in your explanation doesn't quite add up: in the C files which you include there must be some public symbol (something with external linkage, to speak in C) and that symbol would be duplicated if you include it in a testbed file and should (given a decent, modern linker) give an error at link stage.

Comment: @Yunnosch: I want to know if I am correct or if I am misguided
Vroomfondel: Thats what I read to far - strange right?

Comment: Never include .c files. If you need to test private functions, you need to write the test as part of the .c file. This is common practice. If you don't want the test code to be part of source, you can create a branch in your version control system for the test.

Comment: Are you compiling your source into a library and linking the test code with that library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `C` file with static variables - your counters in this case - and this file is included in different files then those static variables will be replicated on every file that the `C` file is included in and in this `C` file itself. As you know, static global variables are only known in the file they are defined at, so you now has many different static variables with the same name.

You need to define your counter only one and extern it in all other files.

So, in a brief, you are incrementing and reading two different variables with the same name.

Comment: Now that you speak it out loud, it makes perfect sense. It also explains why there are no "duplicate linker errors". They are never linked, because they are invisible to the outside. Thanks for speaking out the obvious (that still confused me) ;)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your test runs as a separate process and the regular state machine runs as a separate process. Please verify due to separate entry points different process are created. You can check the number of process getting created while running the tests.

You can create a global mutux variable to verify both uses the same variable globally. This needs to be created at the beginning of the application and a check needs to be added to verify its creation for further code execution.

Comment: There is definitely just one process, since I am running on a embedded device. With FreeRTOS, the tests run in a seperate task, but that should not matter, right? FreeRTOS does not influence the linker, as far as I know

Comment: To confirm your point, try atomic operation on the static variable myInt, gcc supports atomic operations like __sync_fetch_and_add, __sync_fetch_and_sub etc, Check the values for each scenario.